# Display contents of a JSON file from a download link with Angular 7

Tags: json, angular, url

I need to display the contents of a JSON from a URL returned from my API. When you click the URL it triggers a download of the JSON file. Is there a way to display the contents of the file from the URL in the UI without downloading it?

I am using Angular 7. I have tried

Here is what I have tried so far:

(from my service)

```
getJSON(jsonFile: string): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get(jsonFile);
}
```

(from my component)

```
this.dataService.getJSON(this.blobPath).subscribe(data => {
  this.blobRes = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right. You just need to display `this.blobRes` in you component template :

```
{{ blobRes }}
```

I made quick working demo with your API link: [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2pxz3d)

Comment: I mean what I get back from the api is URL for a file like this one: https://support.oneskyapp.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/202761627/example_1.json
When you go to the link it kicks off a file download. I want to use the link to display the file contents in the UI and not have to download the file to view it.

Comment: I have updated the answer to achieve this functionality with your URL for a file